# Solicitud de otro origen bloqueada

Tags: javascript, jquery

este código que tiene como objetivo imprimir en pantalla el codigo html de una busqueda:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, 
        maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
        <title>Web</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>      
                <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://www.google.com/search",
                data: {
                    q: "banana"
                },
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "html",
            }).done(console.log)
            .fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
                console.log("Sorry,there was an error" + status + error)
            })
                </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

dicta estos mensajes en consola:

`Solicitud desde otro origen bloqueada: la política de mismo origen impide leer el recurso remoto en https://www.google.com/search?q=banana (razón: falta la cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'). Código de estado: 200.`
`Sorry,there was an errorerror`

Si cambio la llamada a funcion ajax agregandole el header correspondiente asi:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://www.google.com/search",
        data: {
            q: "banana"
        },
    type: "GET",
        dataType: "html",
        headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
        }
})
```

imprime lo siguiente en la consola:
`Solicitud desde otro origen bloqueada: la política de mismo origen impide leer el recurso remoto en https://www.google.com/search?q=banana (razón: falta la cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'). Código de estado: 405.`
`Solicitud de origen cruzado bloqueada: La misma política de origen no permite la lectura de recursos remotos en https://www.google.com/search?q=banana. (Razón: Solicitud CORS sin éxito). Código de estado: (null).`
`Sorry,there was an errorerror`

Quisiera saber que hacer para hacer la solicitud y me imprima el codigo html de la página.

Comment: Directamente desde javascript no puedes. Los errores de CORS normalmente se solucionan de lado del servidor, en este caso de lado de Google (es decir no puedes hacer nada). Lo unico que se me ocurre es que crees tu propio servidor que haga la petición a google y te devuelva el HTML. Pero es un tema extenso de explicar.

Comment: Ya trate de hacer la peticion desde un servidor con la extension para vscode live server.

Comment: Tal cual está, no se va a poder; para usar las búsquedas de google, existe la API de Google Search.